# equivalent of flask.request.url in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

i am trying to change google oauth2 example code from python flask to FastAPI.

this is the code

```
def oauth2callback():
# Specify the state when creating the flow in the callback so that it can
# verified in the authorization server response.
state = flask.session['state']

flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES, state=state)
flow.redirect_uri = flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True)
# Use the authorization server's response to fetch the OAuth 2.0 tokens.
print("this is the flask request url -----------", flask.request.url)
**authorization_response = flask.request.url**

flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
# Store credentials in the session.
# ACTION ITEM: In a production app, you likely want to save these
#              credentials in a persistent database instead.

credentials = flow.credentials
flask.session['credentials'] = credentials_to_dict(credentials)

creds = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
    **flask.session['credentials'])

return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('test_api_request'))
```

the line is **authorization_response = flask.request.url**
the value of it is "http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback?state=79aCVleeoxdA4bYgo5YnzuK8vsvM22&code=4%2F0AWtgzh611Sc3dhUo_pqQSa4RVTEZOgX9rJHc328XCJ4UmLvHdg5zz3t1k8VS3ihZwKMEA&scope=email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.readonly+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.modify+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fgmail.labels+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=none"

now i just want to change this line to the same in fastapi, i have tried request.url.path but it gives me "/oauth2callback" or sometimes None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request.url` property is a string-like object, and you can get the full URL by casting it as a string.

i.e. `str(request.url)`

You can also access properties of the URL individually - more information on this can be found in [Starlette's documentation](https://www.starlette.io/requests).